# Unpacking kwargs in python unittest Mock where the keyword argument has 'dot' in name

Tags: python, keyword-argument, python-unittest.mock

According to unittest doc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock) and verified personally,

```
mock = Mock(some_attribute='eggs', **{'method.return_value': 3, 'other.side_effect': KeyError})
```

works.

Also verified

```
mock = Mock(some_attribute='eggs', method.return_value=3, other.side_effect=KeyError)
```

will raise `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Should these 2 be equivalent at syntax level? What happened in the dict unpacking?
If 2 doesn't work, how is 1 being handled? Is there a way to achieve the Mock init without using "**"?

Tested snippet 1: works;
Tested snippet 2: raise error;
Asked ChatGPT-3.5: It tells nothing valuable but keeps contradicting itself and apologizing to me. Maybe I should upgrade to 4.

Comment: For the comment about ChatGPT: this is a true AI limitation, because as it only compiles tons of document *whithout deeply understanding them*, it can only provide relevant answers for question that could feed a FAQ. And fails miserabily on any corner case. That is the reason why human beeings will still be necessary despite what some magazines and bloggers could pretend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntactic problem. When you unpack a dict, the only *syntactic* requirement for the keys is that they shall be valid *strings*. No more no less.
And `'method.return_value'` **is** a valid string.

But when you pass keyword parameters, the *syntactic* requirement is that they shall be valid identifiers. And as it contain a dot, `method.return_value` is not a valid identifier.

You are just realizing that the *unpacking `kwargs` idiom* is more powerful than simply passing arbitrary but declared parameters. With the `**dict` idiom, the Python interpretor uses a short-circuit under the hood and directly uses the passed dictionary to build the `kwargs` parameter *whitout any requirement for the keys to be valid identifiers*. Unsure whether it was really intended at language definition time, but it is now definitely part of the language and has real use cases like your example.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and inspiring. I never realized these details before.